# How can I change layout of '>' output file

Tags: shell, stdout

I use '>' output a file, but I don't like its form; I want to change its layout? 
For example: special string behind wrap

The file look like:

```
#0 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   #1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #2xxxxxxxxxx
```

I want it to look like:

```
#0 xxxxxxxxxxxx
#1 xxxxxxxxxxxx
#2 xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: @squiguy This is a detailed?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easiest to make the program generating the data do the generation the way you want?  Is it always a single line of output?  Is it always 3 fields per line?  Are the split fields always `#` and a single digit?  Can the `xxx` material contain leading digits?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler  Sorry,I said wrong.I use linux Virtual machine, export file to windows.But there is a problem,in linux end of line have (line feed)\n.In windows ,it need CRLF(carriage return line feed)\n\r for line feed.So  datas show in a line.How can I change that?

Comment: On your virtual machine just run `perl -pi.bak -e 's#\n#\r\n#g' file`

Comment: @squiguy Oh,great,thank you very much.And can you explain principle
,I want to understand in deep.

Comment: @squiguy Ok,fine.Can I ask easy question: Can '/' replace '#'?

Comment: Yes: you can use any character except backslash, or the letters n or r instead of `#`, and specifically, you could use slash instead of hash.  A simpler regex is `perl -p -e 's/$/\r/'`, which prefixes each end of line with a carriage return, to give you DOS-style CRLF line endings.  You might also find a program `utod` or `unix2dos` which will do the same transform.  You _could_ use `sed` instead of Perl (but Perl is probably neater).  The ways to deal with the problem are manifold.  It does need to be handled in the Linux VM, though; it is harder to deal with on the Windows side.

Comment: @choujayyl This will do a search and replace of the newline with the desired carriage return and newline.  It is a Perl construct that helps do a search and replace in the program.  And yes, the `#` is a choice to help make it more readable.  You can choose just about any symbol you are comfortable with as long as you are consistent.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this logic of prefixing newline before the # character.

```
echo "#0 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   #1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #2xxxxxxxxxx" | sed 's/\#/\n#/g'
```